# How to create an interface with an unknown amount of string properties and one specific property with number type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, interface

I have an object that contains an unknown amount of error messages and exactly one property with a type number. How to create an interface for this object?

```
  interface IFormErrors {
    [key: string]: string; // So here is an unknown amount of strings
  }

  const initialFormErrors: IFormErrors = {
    nameErr: "",
    emailErr: "",
    linkErr: "",
    errorCounter: 0,
  };
```

Comment: Is the property with type number always the `errorCounter` key or can it be any key?

Comment: Yes, it is always errorCounter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve exactly what you are looking for is to use an intersection type:

```
  type IFormErrors = { errorCounter: number } & {
    [key: string]: string; // So here is an unknown amount of strings
  }

  const initialFormErrors: IFormErrors = {
    nameErr: "",
    emailErr: "",
    linkErr: "",
    errorCounter: 0,
  };
```

This is a bit of a workaround as Typescript doesn't let you have properties of other types once you define an index signature. The recommended way to do this would be to use a nested index signature to avoid the problem:

```
interface IFormErrors {
  errorCounter: number;
  // you can name this property whatever you like, `errors` was just
  // what I came up with
  errors: { 
    [key: string]: string; // So here is an unknown amount of strings
  }
}
```

I recommend reading this section of the Typescript Deep Dive gitbook to learn more about how to work efficiently with index signatures: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#declaring-an-index-signature

Answer (score 0):

It is doable, but there are some limitations:

```js
interface IFormErrors {
    [key: string]: string; // So here is an unknown amount of strings
}

type Result = IFormErrors & {
    errorCounter: number;
}

const merge = <T, U>(a: T, b: U) => ({ ...a, ...b })
const build = (obj: IFormErrors, errorCounter: number) => merge(obj, { errorCounter })

const result = build({ a: '2' }, 5)

const anyProperty = result.sdf // string
const numberProperty = result.errorCounter // number



/**
 * But you are unable to create literal type
 */
const y: Result = { // error
    a: '23',
    errorCounter: 42
}
```

`result` variable has `Result` type - which is exactly what you want